# How to group all Files in folder that have same six digit number in their file name in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, grouping

I am trying to come up with a script that looks at a folder and then copies all files that have the same timestamp in their file name together into another folder but I'm struggling with the grouping part already.

the file names look something like this (number to group by in bold):

```
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.txt
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.dat
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.exe
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.txt
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.dat
```

So they should be grouped and copied like

```
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.exe
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.txt
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.dat

mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.exe
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.txt
mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.dat
```

For this I tried to group them using regex but I only manage to group them if they **contain** a 6 digit number and not if they have identical ones in their name. I also thought about using the Index inside the filename but the timestamp is not necessarily always in the same position in the name.
Can somebody help ? this is my first time using ps

```
$GroupedFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
    Group-Object {($\_ | Get-Item).BaseName -match '\d{6}'}
```

this is my latest attempt

Comment: Is there any need to actually *group* them in the code? It sounds like all you need to do is extract the timestamp substring from each filename in turn and move it into the appropriate subfolder - the grouping in code seems like extra unnecessary work (unless you’re using it in other parts of your code as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the structure you have in your filenames to split them into pieces and then re-join the desired pieces together to group the files as wanted ... like this:

```
$GroupedFiles = 
    Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
        Group-Object {
            ($_.BaseName -split '_')[2..3] -join '_'
        }
```

Comment: Wow that was fast thank you so much :) Just for my understanding, this splits the original filename at every '_' and then joins the second and third group of those together as the criteria to group after ?

Comment: @NilsWild Exactly. 

Answer (score 2):

**[Olaf's helpful answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) provides an *alternative*** to your regex-based approach.

To **address your question *as asked*** (extraneous `\` removed):

> ```bash
> Group-Object {($_ | Get-Item).BaseName -match '\d{6}'}
> ```

Indeed, this groups based on *whether or not* the input file names contain a 6-digit sequence, which with your sample input yields just *one* group.
The reason is that your `-match` operation yields a *Boolean* (`[bool]`), i.e. either `$true` or `$false`.

What you instead want as a grouping criterion is the *the specific 6-digit sequence* in each filename.

To that end, you can use the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), in which the matched text after a (single-value) [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation is stored:

However, to also exclude *false positives*, your regex needs to be more sophisticated, given that `\d{6}` would also match `20230925` for instance, i.e. an *8*-digit token.

Therefore:

```bash
$groupedFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
  Group-Object {
    # To also include the date part: '\D(\d{8}_\d{6})\D'
    if ($_.BaseName -match '\D(\d{6})\D') { $Matches.1 }
  }
```

- `$_.BaseName` is sufficient to get the base name of each input file-info object - no need for `Get-Item`
- `\D` matches a non-digit, so surrounding `\d{6}` with this construct ensures that what is matched is *exactly* 6 digits long.
- Enclosing `\d{6}` in `(...)` creates a *capture group*, meaning that what it is captured separately, and by default accessible via the *index* of the group in `$Matches`. That is, `$Matches.1` (or `$Matches[1]`) contains the actual 6-digit sequence found.

Note that I've kept the regex general; if you're willing to make assumptions about the surrounding characters, something like `'_(\d{6})_` would suffice.
Also, if it were possible for the sequence to be at the very *start or end* of a name, the regex would have to be tweaked.

Finally, the 6-digit sequence seemingly represents just the time-of-day part; to also include the *date* part, use:

```bash
'\D(\d{8}_\d{6})\D'
```

---

An alternative would be to use a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation:

```bash
$groupedFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
  Group-Object {
    $_.BaseName -replace '^.*\D(\d{6})\D.*$', '$1'
  }
```

Note how the modified regex now consumes the entire input string and replaces it with what the first capture group (`$1`) captured, effectively *extracting* the digit sequence of interest.

While more concise, there is a subtle difference to the `-match` approach:

- Should there be files whose names do *not* match the regex, they are grouped *by their full base name*, because `-replace` passes the input string through as-is if it doesn't match the given regex.
- By contrast, the `-match` approach would put all non-matching files into a *single* group.

For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/x1iwE4/1); a variant that also matches a 6-digit sequence at the start and end of an input string as well as in isolation:
`'^(?:.*\D|)(\d{6})(?:\D.*)?$'`

Comment: Thank you so much, especially for the hint about the false positives due to 8-digit numbers (kind of obviously) containing 6-digit numbers, didn't even consider that until now. However I used -match in place of -replace because I wasn't sure if -replace modified the file names (not an option), also it is a given that all files have that 6-digit timestamp. Also used Get-ChildItem to also be able to calculate the file size of each group. But this was incredibly helpful :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NilsWild; no, `-replace` wouldn't modify anything; its return value is merely used as the grouping criterion; if all file names have a 6-digit group, the `-replace` solution is equivalent to the `-match` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex

```
$response = @(
'mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.txt',
'mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.dat',
'mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.exe',
'mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.txt',
'mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.dat'
)

$pattern = '.*D-000_(?<date>\d+_\d+).*'

$groups = $response | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
$groups.Matches | Group-Object {$_.Groups['date'].Value}
```

results

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 20230925_142604           {mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142604_kok.txt, mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_2023...
    3 20230925_142634           {mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_20230925_142634_kok.exe, mork-work03_lork1360-D-000_2023...


PS C:\Users\joel>
```